# Is it possible to connect an Android device directly to a computing device with an Ethernet adapter?

Tags: networking, ethernet, android

When an Android device is connected to a network hub via a USB-Ethernet adapter (i.e. Android device - USB-Ethernet adapter - Ethernet cable - Hub), everything works perfectly.  The device has Internet access.

I am trying to do some testing by connecting the Android device directly to another computing device (e.g. a computer).  I have tried both a regular CAT5 cable and a cross-over cable to no avail.  Settings > Ethernet > Use Ethernet always shows "DISCONNECTED".

I have an app on the Android device detecting packets sent from the connected devices.  It does not work apparently because there is no connection as indicated by "DISCONNECTED".

Could anyone offer a tip on this?

Comment: did you enable internet sharing on your computer?

Comment: @MustafaAKTAŞ  I am not trying to access internet by the connection.  I will edit my question to explain more specifically what I am trying to do.